# error event onclick of RadioButton in .xml

Tags: android, onclick, radio-button

When I add an on click event in .xml I don't have and error like this

[image]

Here is my code

```
<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/dientich" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickHandler"
    android:text="dien tich" />
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/thetich"
    android:onClick=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:text="the tich" />
 </RadioGroup>
```

Thank you!

Comment: <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/dientich"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickHandler"
            android:text="dien tich" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/thetich"
            android:onClick=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="the tich" />

    </RadioGroup>

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better way is to set a listener in your code

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, optionId ->
    when (optionId) {
        R.id.dientich -> {
            // do something when radio button dientich is selected
        }
        R.id.thetich -> {
            // do something when radio button thetich is selected
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Can you please refer to this link**

```
 <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="User 1"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

//your code

}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton